# Объясните, пожалуйста, решение каты на codewars (js)

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять [кату](https://www.codewars.com/kata/567ed5db4089538eea000010/javascript) на кодварс. Нужно поправить код:

```
function launchAll(launchMissile) {
  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      launchMissile(i);
    }, i * 1000);
  }
}
```

Решение простое: заменить *var* на *let*. Понимаю, что это скорее всего как-то связано со scope, но не догоняю как оно влияет в данном случае. Может кто-нибудь объяснить совсем простыми словами, для "чайников"?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/var  ... https://medium.com/nuances-of-programming/%D0%B2-%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-var-let-%D0%B8-const-%D0%B2-javascript-3084bfe9f7a3

Comment: Простыми словами: let создаёт новую переменную на каждой итерации, var - нет